# Common home folder for slurm cluster user on nodes and front end

Tags: slurm

I am trying to put together a SLURM cluster with an Odroid XU4 front end (Ubuntu 20.04-5.4 mate), Odroid MC1 nodes (12 nodes total: Ubuntu 20.04.1-5.4-minimal), and an Odroid HC1 NFS server (OpenMediaVault; Armbian 21.02.3 Buster with Linux 4.14.222-odroidXU4).

I can see and change the state of all the nodes, and submit jobs (using slurmR or rslurm), and all the nodes have access to an NFS share work folder (autofs provides access), but from what I gather (looking at slurmd.log), all of the nodes (same user on all: slurm) and the front end need to share a home folder for the user.

I have tried copying the user ("slurm") files (cp -r /home/slurm/.) from /home/slurm to /mountfold/homes/slurm (the NFS share), and creating a link in /home to the NFS share (ln -s /mountfold/homes/slurm) but when I attempt to login from the mate login screen, it just blinks and returns to the login page.

I have also tried (with the link in place) the --home /home/slurm option of adduser, followed by: chown -R slurm:slurm /home/slurm (where /home/slurm is the link, and not the folder) with the same result.

So...I can't even get the front end to have a user home folder on the NFS server, let alone have all of the nodes share that folder for the same user, and I have run out of ideas.

Comment: This may just be a MATE issue. When I make a "slurm" directory on /mountfold/homes/, and a link in /home/, then adduser --home /home/slurm followed by: chown -R slurm:slurm /home/slurm, I can su to "slurm" in the terminal, but I can't log in from the login screen when I restart the computer.

Comment: AND I can do the same on the nodes and ssh to the user there with no issues, so it definitely is a MATE issue.

Answer (score 0):

It turned out to be a permission issue using:

chmod 774 slurm

in /mountfold/homes did the trick, as all users are in the same group.